# Define missing class for TypeScript module in my own code base

Tags: typescript

I installed https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet via npm along with `@types/react-leaflet`. It works fine if I import things defined in `@types/react-leaflet`, like this

```
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
```

However, if I tried to import something the `@types/react-leaflet` author missed in the declaration file, such as `MapLayer`.

```
import { MapLayer } from "react-leaflet";
```

Then it complains something like this

```
[ts] Module '"/Users/foobar/workspace/webapp/node_modules/@types/react-leaflet/index"' has no exported member 'MapLayer'.
```

If you look at [leaflet source code](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/index.js#L15), you will notice that `MapLayer` is indeed exported. But as the declaration is missing, I still cannot import it. So my question here is, how can I make a declaration for the missing `MapLayer` in my own codebase? I don't want to publish a new npm just for the missing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [augment the module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
declare module "react-leaflet" {
    class MapLayer {
        ...
    }
}
```